# Struts 2 Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, struts2, hibernate-mapping

I am learning Struts2 and Hibernate...

I have an customer class with a geography code associated with each instance.  When I display on my JSP, I need to break down each character with a label.

```
    String geoCode = "1324567890";
```

needs to become

```
    List<String> geoCodeList = "[1][2][3]..."
```

so that I can use a subset in the JSP.

What I tried to do was add another attribute to my Customer.java object.  I have the following:

```
private String geoCode;
private List<String> geoCodeList;

@Column(name = "GEO_CD")
public String getGeoCd() {
    return geoCd;
}

public void setGeoCd(String geoCd) {
    this.geoCd = geoCd;

    geoCdList = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("geo length = " + geoCd.length());
    for (int i=0; i < geoCd.length(); i++) {
        geoCdList.add(geoCd.substring(i,i+1));          
    }
}
```

This all works fine but once I add a getter method for geoCdList I get an error.

```
public List<String> getGeoCdList() {
    return geoCdList;
}
```

The error is:

```
    Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine     type for: java.util.List, at table: Customer, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(geoCdList)]
    Dec 03, 2013 10:21:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/msps-web] threw exception  [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
    org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Customer, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(geoCdList)]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:306)
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:290)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:243)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:464)
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:235)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1362)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1865)
at com.att.msps.database.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
at com.att.msps.database.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
at com.att.msps.customer.view.CustomerAction.<init>(CustomerAction.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:131)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:162)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:151)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:121)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:297)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:553)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

My guess is that it thinks it's a column on the table but I'm not really sure.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to persist `geoCodeList` to database you need to use [`@ElementCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) annotation to map it as collection of strings.

```
@ElementCollection
private List<String> geoCodeList;
```

But if you don't want to persist your list then you need to move your list creation logic from the setter method to some other method and annotate this method with [`@Transient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) annotation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to keep a list in Entity & don't map it in database.

Anyways, you can use `@Transient` annotation on that field & it'll not get persisted.

Comment: If this field is not persisted in db then logic in setter makes no sense.

Comment: @AleksandrM that's what I inferred from the question. He doesn't want to persist, just use it for view purposes.

Comment: Maybe. BUT the logic inside setter makes sense only if this list is persisted.

Comment: Aleksandr & coding_idiot: I don't believe it needs to be persisted.  I kept trying to think of how to break the string up in the JSP but I read that I should do most of that work in the controller but I could not figure out how to get that value from the model and then parse it out in the controller.  Using the @Transient worked but is there a better way to design this?

Comment: Why can't you parse it in the controller?

Comment: I will try that.  I was having problems understanding how to do it if I had a list of customers if my query returned multiple customers but I can take another look.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add any annotations  for geoCdList.

Comment: I don't have any annotation.  Does location matter?